# Vba-Return cell address from a range array

Tags: excel, vba

I read a range on a worksheet and put it into an array.

```
Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = Range("B3:G11")
Dim R As Long
Dim C As Long
For R = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
    For C = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
        Debug.Print Arr(R, C)
    Next C
Next R
```

This returns the value of the cell. Is there a way to get the address of the cell?!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in place of `Debug.Print Arr(R, C)`

```
Debug.Print Cells(R+2, C+1).Address(1,1)
```

One could also fill an array of ranges:

```
Dim Arr() As Range
Dim rng As Range
ReDim Arr(1 To Range("B3:G11").Rows.Count, 1 To Range("B3:G11").Columns.Count) As Range
For Each rng In Range("B3:G11")
    Set Arr(rng.Row - 2, rng.Column - 1) = rng
Next rng
Dim R As Long
Dim C As Long
For R = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
    For C = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
        Debug.Print Arr(R, C).Address
    Next C
Next R
```

Comment: Thank u so much for quick response.. Would u please explain what does R+2, C+1 and (1,1) mean?

Comment: `Cells(Row,Column)` we are just setting the first upper left as B3.  Since R and C start at 1 each we need to move the cell over.  This could also be done with `Range("B3:G11").Cells(R, C).Address(1,1)` which then refers to the range  and not the whole sheet.  the `(1,1)` makes the reference absolute, `(0,0)` would return a relative reference.